# Expected object of backend CPU but got backend CUDA for argument #2 'source'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I have tried other answers but the error is not getting removed. Difference from the other question I am getting is that the last term used in error is '**source**' which I did not find in any question. If possible please also explain the term '**source**' in error. And running code without CPU is working fine.

> I am using Google Colab with GPU enabled.

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
import syft as sy

hook = sy.TorchHook(torch)

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(784,256),
                     nn.ReLU(),
                     nn.Linear(256,128),
                     nn.ReLU(),
                     nn.Linear(128,64),
                     nn.ReLU(),
                     nn.Linear(64,10),
                     nn.LogSoftmax(dim = 1))

model = model.to(device)
```

output :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-136ec343040a> in <module>()
      8                      nn.LogSoftmax(dim = 1))
      9 
---> 10 model = model.to(device)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/syft/frameworks/torch/hook/hook.py in data(self, new_data)
    368 
    369                 with torch.no_grad():
--> 370                     self.set_(new_data)
    371             return self
    372 

RuntimeError: Expected object of backend CPU but got backend CUDA for argument #2 'source'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is related to `PySyft`. As you can see in this [Issue#1893](https://github.com/OpenMined/PySyft/issues/1893), the current [workaround](https://github.com/OpenMined/PySyft/issues/1893#issuecomment-478717757) is to set:

```py
import torch
torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
```

right after `import torch`.

Code:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)  # <-- workaround

import syft as sy
hook = sy.TorchHook(torch)

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(device)

model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(784,256),
                     nn.ReLU(),
                     nn.Linear(256,128),
                     nn.ReLU(),
                     nn.Linear(128,64),
                     nn.ReLU(),
                     nn.Linear(64,10),
                     nn.LogSoftmax(dim = 1))

model = model.to(device)
print(model)
```

Output:

```
cuda
Sequential(
  (0): Linear(in_features=784, out_features=256, bias=True)
  (1): ReLU()
  (2): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=128, bias=True)
  (3): ReLU()
  (4): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=64, bias=True)
  (5): ReLU()
  (6): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=10, bias=True)
  (7): LogSoftmax()
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it's working. Spent 4 hours finding the problem in my code.

Comment: @RavikantSingh it happens to all of us :)